# Как изменить данные в таблице на языке R

Tags: r, rstudio

Подскажите, как на языке R из таблице имеющие данные в следующем формате

```html
Номер заказа 1 | Название продукта 1 | Количество продукта 1<br>
Номер заказа 2 | Название продукта 2 | Количество продукта 2<br>
Номер заказа 3 | Название продукта 3 | Количество продукта 3<br>
```

привести таблицу в вид

```html
XXXXXXXXXXXXX  | Название продукта 1 | Количество продукта 2<br>
Номер заказа 1 |         1           |         1<br>
Номер заказа 2 |         1           |         0<br>
Номер заказа 3 |         0           |         1<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока мне не очень понятна логика, как из вашей таблицы №1, получить таблицу №2

Посмотрите информацию о пакете `tidyr`.

Тут оставлю вам пару ссылок:
1. https://habr.com/ru/post/444622/
2. https://distrland.blogspot.com/2018/04/r-tidyr.html
3. http://biostat-r.blogspot.com/2016/01/tidy-data.html